# Where is the udev database stored and what sets the permission?

Tags: systemd, udev, lsblk

I'm using Debian. When reading [`man lsblk`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/util-linux/lsblk.8.en.html#DESCRIPTION) I see mention of a udev db:

> The lsblk command reads the sysfs filesystem and **udev db** to gather information. If the **udev db** is not available or lsblk is compiled without udev support than it tries to read LABELs, UUIDs and filesystem types from the block device. In this case root permissions are necessary.

I can further find numerous mentions of "database" in [`man udev`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/udev/udev.7.en.html). It seems my `udev` is run under `systemd-udevd`. But I don't see an ability to configure the database location in the man locations, and I don't see it specified in `/lib/systemd/system/udev.service`. Where is the database stored?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The UDev database is stored in `/run/udev/data`. It used to be stored in `/dev/.udev*` before `/run` was introduced and the location was configurable in [`udev.conf`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/udev.conf.5.html) but it's no longer possible.

Comment: It would be nice if _something_ documented `/run/udev/data`

Comment: Is `/dev/.udev.tdb` a typo? I have a machine which has no `/run/` but does have `/dev/.udev/db/`

Comment: It's wasn't a typo, my original source was [this man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/udev) which says the default is `/dev/.udev.tdb`, but it looks like this is/was different for different distributions and various locations in `/dev` were used in the past so I changed the answer to `/dev/.udev*`.